# AndroidApp: not using the full screen resolution

Tags: android, resolution

I tried to test Android-programming on my phone and not the emulator. There the apps only use some little space in center of the screen. In the emulator everything works fine. So I also tried the 'Hello world'-app. But there is the same problem. The phone is an HTD HD2 with HyperDroid. So it has changed density to 167. When using width and height from onSizeChanged it says 320x430 or 480x270.

Is there a way to use the whole screen?

EDIT 1:

It also uses less screen on emulator with changed density. This also means that the titlebar doesn't use the whole width. Here is a screenshot of the emulator: [klick](http://tinypic.com/r/29uzzly/7)

Comment: Which android version are you building for?

Comment: Normally 2.3, but it's the same on an emulator with 2.2 with changed density to 167.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to apply this for full application then

Add this line to **Application tab**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

otherwise if you want for individual activities then

Add this line to "Activity tab properties"

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: I tried to apply it for full application and it removed the Title Bar, but it still does not use full screen resolution. It now uses 480x320 / 320x480 .

Comment: then i think, you have not used the layout width and height correctly, make sure to put layout width and height fill-parent to cover full screen area

Comment: I set both to fill_parent. Like I said: the normal 'Hello world'-app with layout set to fill parent doesn't use the full space. But I think it depends on the changed density.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have put the

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="xx" android:targetSdkVersion="xx"/>`

tag in your manifest file. This solved this issue for me.